# Need to prove the identity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem is that I tried to prove through the Mellin and Laplace transforms but nothing happened
If you know literature where is this proof can you send it?
$$\frac{1}{x^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma \left ( s \right )}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }y^{s-1}e^{-xy}dy,s>0,x>0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
1 = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty (xy)^{s}\frac{1}{y} \mathrm{e}^{-xy}dy
$$
wh
if we set $xy = z$ we have
$$
\int_0^\infty z^{s} \frac{1}{y}\mathrm{e}^{-z}\frac{1}{x}dz
$$
or
$$
\int_0^\infty z^{s} \frac{1}{xy}\mathrm{e}^{-z}dz = \int_0^\infty z^{s-1}\mathrm{e}^{-z}dz = \Gamma(s)
$$
putting it all together
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty (xy)^{s}\frac{1}{y} \mathrm{e}^{-xy}dy = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}  \cdot \Gamma(s) = 1
$$

Comment: We have 1 / x ^ s

Comment: @Dmitry Read carefully the answer of Chinny84